# C#/WPF - Get ScrollViewer scroll position?

Tags: c#, wpf

Okay, so, everyone knows how to set the scroll position of a ScrollViewer. Entire essays and blog entries have been written about `ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset()`, and there are a good few hundred questions with answers about it here.

So, I enter:

```
myScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(280);
```

... and it so kindly scrolls to that location.

The question is, *what property now contains 280*, so I can retrieve it later?

(Hint: `myScrollViewer.VerticalOffset` and `ContentVerticalOffset` are both 0; `myScrollViewer.ScrollInfo` just plain doesn't exist.)

EDIT: Apparently I need a more detailed demonstration.

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  double scrollTarget = 280;
  MessageBox.Show("Target: " + scrollTarget.ToString());
  myScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollTarget);
  MessageBox.Show("Now: " + myScrollViewer.VerticalOffset);
}
```

I must reiterate that this **does scroll** as intended. Goes right exactly where I want it to. But, `myScrollViewer.VerticalOffset` is set at 0.

Comment: Reading MSDN, `VerticalOffset` or `ContentVerticalOffset` should give you the correct value... at what point are you accessing these properties (when they evaluate to 0)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The solution is to manually call `myScrollViewer.UpdateLayout()` after `myScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset()`. Then, `myScrollViewer.VerticalOffset` will have the expected value.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" and VerticalScrollOffset will be 280 after LayoutUpdated event has been fired.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling the myscrollViewer in the constructor of the window.

You can call them when you click a button or in loaded method for the window, so that the value gets updated in vertical offset values. That is, these value gets updated after you initialize your window!