# WPF set position usercontrol in parent scrollviewer programmatically

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a usercontrol in a scrollviewer. I want to zoom in to the usercontrol on mousewheel scroll. I manage to catch the mousewheelscroll and resize the usercontrol. So far so good!

Next I want the mouseposition to be the point to zoom in to. Therefore I need to position the usercontrol relative to the scrollviewer. And it has to be done through code.

So, I need something like Usercontrol.left and usercontrol.top, but these left and top properties don't exist.

How can I do that?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151603/c-wpf-get-scrollviewer-scroll-position?rq=1) might be helpful, it contains some code for vertical scrolling.

Comment: What is the parent container of the UserControl

Comment: The parent container of the usercontrol is the scrollviewer. The base control for the usercontrol is a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which is ok for me.
I think it is not possible to do this with a scrollviewer. Therefore I replaced the scrollviewer with a canvas. Now the possition can be set by:

Canvas.SetLeft(MyUserControl, 50)