# How to get synchronize the two scrollbars in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollbar

I'm learning WPF these days.

I made some XAML like below.

```
  <TextBox x:Name="TxtHex" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="500"                              
           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
           Grid.Column="1"
           HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
           VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
           Style="{StaticResource Textbox}"/>

  <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2">
           <TextBox x:Name="TxtAnsi" Margin="0,0,5,0" IsReadOnly="True" 
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                    Style="{StaticResource Textbox}"/>
  </ScrollViewer>
```

I made two TextBoxes with VerticlaScrollBar and ScrollViewer.

I want this two scrollbar to have the same value when one scollbar changed value.

I mean, I want to synchronize the two scroll bars.

So, I want to get value of scollbar and set value to scrollbar.

I've been searching about this, But I can't get any information.

Please give me some tips if someone has good idea.

Thank you.

Comment: This question has been asked quite a few times.  Here is one instance: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13151603/107899

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set your XAML code(note: you can change the background)

```
<TextBox ScrollBar.Scroll="TxtHex_Scroll" AcceptsReturn="True" x:Name="TxtHex" 
IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="500"                              
           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
           HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
           VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="22,231,271.6,10" 
Background="#FFE2E2E2"
           />

        <ScrollViewer ScrollBar.Scroll="Scroll_Scroll" x:Name="scroll" 
Margin="22,47,271.6,194">
             <TextBox x:Name="TxtAnsi" IsReadOnly="True" AcceptsReturn="True" 
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
Background="#FFF7EEEE"
                    />
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Then, go to code:

```
private void TxtHex_Scroll(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            scroll.ScrollToVerticalOffset(TxtHex.VerticalOffset);
            scroll.UpdateLayout();

        }

        private void Scroll_Scroll(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            TxtHex.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scroll.VerticalOffset);
            scroll.UpdateLayout();
        }
```

Do not forget to add your text inside it. So, when you scroll a one, the other one will scroll in the same value. But both of them need enough text to scroll.